# Add job attribute if another job is enabled

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to add some attribute to a job only if another job from the pipeline is enabled (by the `only:` keyword)

Probably the `rules:if` attribute could be used but I don't know how.

Is it possible to do such thing and how?

Comment: could you give an example ?